# How Add UIActivity Indicator on ImageView in swift using Alamofire Image

Tags: swift, alamofireimage

I am Using **AlamofireImage** library and i want to add a `subview` (UIActivityIndicator) on ImageView until image did not download. but have no idea how to do it.

```
self.imgView_main.af_setImageWithURL(downloadURL)
```

image is downloading. but how to show `UIActivityIndicator` please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `completion:` function for that, First start the `activityIndicator` and stop the indicator when you get the image in `completion` block like this.

```
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
self.listImageView.af_setImageWithURL(
    NSURL(string: list!.image!)!,
    placeholderImage: nil,
    filter: nil,
    imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.5),
    completion: { response in
        let image = response.result.value // UIImage Object
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
)
```

Comment: Have great day mate :)

Comment: the completion handler is called before the image gets downloaded, what am I missing?

Comment: @Mirko why do you think that completion handler is called before? Can you show what you are trying ?

Comment: @NiravD problem solved. I had another call to `af_setImageWithURL ` earlier with no completion handler causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an **extension** to **UIImageView**. Take a look at the [link](https://gist.github.com/paresh-masmedi/c8dd892434960787cc8d4765dcbc7911)

The above link has all the required methods and make necessary changes based on your requirements to show and hide the activity indicator.

```
func downloadImage(withURL url: URL, placeholderImage: UIImage? = nil, completion: ((AFIDataResponse<UIImage>) -> Void)? = nil) {
    //Show activity indicator
    self.showActivityIndicator()
    self.af.setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, completion: { response in
        if case .success(_) = response.result {
            //Hide activity indicator
            self.hideActivityIndicator()
        }
        
        completion?(response)
    })
}
```